# Mocha async tests, reuse the same request

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm testing an HTTP server. I was hoping I could pass `done` to `describe()`, instead of just to `it()`, something like this:

```
var request = require('supertest');

describe('Item', function(done){
    request(app).get('/').end(function(req, res){
        it('should have one thing', function(){
            // Assert on res.body
        });

        it('should have another thing', function(){
            // Assert on res.body
        });

        it('should have more things', function(){
            // Assert on res.body
        });

        done();
    });
});
```

This won't work, mocha never runs the tests.

The following code does work, but each time making a new HTTP request, I would prefer to use the same one.

```
describe('Item', function(){
    it('should have one thing', function(done){
        request(app).get('/').end(function(req, res){
            // Assert on res.body
            done();
        }
    });

    it('should have another thing', function(done){
        request(app).get('/').end(function(req, res){
            // Assert on res.body
            done();
        }
    });

    it('should more things', function(done){
        request(app).get('/').end(function(req, res){
            // Assert on res.body
            done();
        }
    });
});
```

**How can I run the tests against the same response?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you test the exact same request - then why are the `assert`s distributed across multiple tests? IMHO there are two options:

- Either they really belong together, then move everything into one single test, and your problem is gone.
- Or they do not belong together, then do not work on a single request, but on individual ones to avoid side-effects. Anyway, your problem will be gone, too.

The way you're doing it currently you may have inter-dependencies between your tests, and this is - IMHO - very bad test style.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I was trying to test things like: *1) - is JSON*, *2) - response data properties*. You're right, they don't belong together.

Comment: Also, if I had done it like I wanted, it would have skewed the test completion times.